# Class with methods to choose search category

Tags: javascript, jquery

Everything works, but my hard coding is worse:

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/GriAl/pen/ojRKyB)

```
<div class="header__search">
<form action="">
  <div class="search__input-wrapper">
    <div class="search__dropdown">
      <div class="search__dropdown-trigger btn-default">
        <span>Portfolio</span>
        <i class="search__dropdown-icon"></i>
      </div>
      <ul class="search__dropdown-list">
        <li class="dropdown-list__item">portfolio</li>
        <li class="dropdown-list__item">blog</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="search__input" placeholder="Search in portfolio">
    <i class="search__icon search__icon-blog"></i>
    <i class="search__icon search__icon-portfolio"></i>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="search__submit btn-submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    // Class with methods to choose search category
    var chooseCategory = {

        getDropdownMenu: function(){
                $('.search__dropdown-trigger').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var categoryList = $(this).next('.search__dropdown-list');

                if (categoryList.prop('hidden')) {;
                    categoryList.removeProp('hidden');
                }else{
                    categoryList.prop('hidden','hidden');
                }
            });
        },

        chooseDropdownItem: function() {
            $('.dropdown-list__item').click(function () {
                var name = $(this).text();
                var categoryList = $(this).parent('.search__dropdown-list');

                // For this need better separate method, but...
                // Impure function((((
                $('.search__dropdown-trigger span').text(name);
                $('.search__input').attr("placeholder", "Search in "+name);
                if(name=='portfolio'){
                    $('.search__icon-portfolio').show();
                    $('.search__icon-blog').hide();
                }else{
                    $('.search__icon-blog').show();
                    $('.search__icon-portfolio').hide();
                }
                // $('.search__icon').toogle('search__icon-'+name);
                categoryList.prop('hidden','hidden');
            });
        },

        // replaceText: function () {
        //  $('.search__dropdown-trigger').text(this.chooseDropdownItem());
        // },

        init: function(){
            this.getDropdownMenu();
            this.chooseDropdownItem();
        }



    };

    chooseCategory.init();

});
```

This code must do:

After click on `.search__dropdown-trigger` appear `.search__dropdown-list`.
In this list we have two categories "Blog" and "Portfolio", after click on some of them in `.search__dropdown-trigger`>span paste the relevant text node, show the relevant icon `.search__icon-blog` or `.search__icon-portfolio` and change input's placeholder "Search in portfolio".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Create a Private Scope

The first thing I would do it to move your code into a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) by using an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).  This will help prevent collisions between your code and any other code by creating a private scope.  It also prevents your code from [polluting the global scope](https://gist.github.com/hallettj/64478). One other thing it will allow you to do is to refer to `jQuery` as `$`.

You should also [use strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) for your code. By using this, it forces the JavaScript engine to prevent common mistakes in your code (like not `var`ing your variables and a lot more things).

```
(function( $, undefined ) {
  //undefined is needed only for really old browsers
  'use strict';
  // your code goes here
})( jQuery );
```

### Cache Your Selectors

The next thing I would recommend is caching your jQuery selectors.  This will [improve the overall performance of your code](http://jsperf.com/why-cache-jquery-selectors). I tend to preface my cached selectors with a `$` so I know they are jQuery objects.

```
var $search = $('header__search');
var $trigger = $search.find('.search__dropdown-trigger');
var $categoryList = $search.find('.search__dropdown-list');
```

By caching the `header__search` object, jQuery only has to search this container instead of the entire DOM every time.  A basic rule of thumb is, **if you use a selector more than once, cache it**.

### Updating getDropDownMenu

Next, your `getDropDownMenu` function can be simplified if you just toggle the `hidden` property instead of removing it.

```
  var isHidden = !( $categoryList.prop('hidden') ); //swap value btwn true/false
  $categoryList.prop('hidden',  isHidden );
```

### Updating chooseDropDownItem

You can change your `chooseDropDownItem` function similarly by using the `toggle` method ([jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)) for the icons.  The `toggle` method can take a boolean value to determine whether to display or not.  For example:

```
$('.search__icon-portfolio').toggle( ( name === 'portfolio' ) );
$('.search__icon-blog').toggle( (name === 'blog') );
```

So in the above code, if `name` is "*blog*", then the boolean value is `true` for the `search__icon-blog`so the element will be displayed, but it would be `false` for the `search__icon-portfolio`.  This can be simplified even further by chaining all of your selections together by using the cached `$search` variable above.

```
$search
  .find('.search__input').attr( 'placeholder', 'Search in ' + name ).end()
  .find('.search__icon-portfolio').toggle( ( name === 'portfolio' ) ).end()
  .find('.search__icon-blog').toggle( (name === 'blog') );
```

Then `end` method ([jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/end/)) returns you back to your previous selection (in this case `$search`). Also, notice I used the [identity operator (===) instead of the equality operator (==)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-JavaScript-comparisons).  I recommend doing this in all cases.

### Use .on For Events

You should also use the more current `on` method ([jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) instead of the old `click` method.  The `click` method calls `on` behind the scenes anyway so just skip the middleman.  Also, I would recommend using [delegated events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on) instead of creating click events on each dropdown item.  This will improve performance as well since there are fewer events being tracked on the page.

```
$categoryList.on( 'click', '.dropdown-list__item', function( e ) {
 // code here
}
```

This function uses the cached selector from above. When a `dropdown-list__item` is clicked, it bubbles up to the parent element and we handle the event there.  This way there is only one click event for ALL of the items.

### Simplify document.ready

Also, I would remove most of your code from the `document.ready` event.  It is unnecessary.  Go ahead and declare your functions before the event and only call the `init` method inside of it.

```
$(function() {  //shorthand for $(document).ready
  chooseCategory.init();
});
```

### Public and Private Methods

Last, I would assume that your `chooseDropDownItem`and `getDropdownMenu` are private methods and only your `init` method is a public method.  You can make the first two private methods by placing them outside of your `chooseCategory` object.  Since they are all part of the same scope, the `init` function will still have access to them but they will be unavailable globally.

```
function chooseDropdownItem() {}
function getDropdownMenu(){}
function init() {}
var chooseCategory = {
  init : init
};
```

### Final Code

So, if you were to implement all of these changes, then your code would look like this:

```
(function( $, undefined ) {

  'use strict';

  var $search = $('header__search');
  var $trigger = $search.find('.search__dropdown-trigger');
  var $categoryList = $search.find('.search__dropdown-list');

  function init() {
    getDropdownMenu();
    chooseDropdownItem();
  }

  function getDropdownMenu(){
    $trigger.on( 'click', function( e ) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var isHidden = !( $categoryList.prop('hidden') );
      $categoryList.prop('hidden',  isHidden );
    });
  }

  function chooseDropdownItem() {
    $categoryList.on( 'click', '.dropdown-list__item', function( e ) {
    var name = $(this).text();
    $trigger.find('span').text( name );

    //adding this because I am not sure of your text values
    //remove if you don't need it
    name = name.toLowerCase();

    $search
      .find('.search__input').attr( 'placeholder', 'Search in ' + name ).end()
      .find('.search__icon-portfolio').toggle( ( name === 'portfolio' ) ).end()
      .find('.search__icon-blog').toggle( (name === 'blog') );
    $categoryList.prop( 'hidden', true );
    });
  }

  var chooseCategory = {
    init : init
  };

  $(function() {
    chooseCategory.init();
  });

})( jQuery );
```

I hope that helps. Let me know if you have any further questions.